# angular directive not listening to changes in outer scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm currently trying to get my directive to listen to changes happening to a specific variable in the parent scope. For that purpose I came up with the following code which runs fine the first time the controller gets loaded but is not picking up the change to the variable gridCells in the second part running in the $timeout.

Anyone able to give me a hint what I'm doing wrong here?

Controller:

```
$scope.gridCells = [];
$scope.gridCells.push({value: '1'});
$scope.gridCells.push({value: '2'});
$scope.gridCells.push({value: '1'});
$scope.gridCells.push({value: '2'});

// this change is not reflected in the directive
$timeout(function() {
  console.log('push');
  $scope.gridCells.push({value: '2'});
  $scope.gridCells.push({value: '1'});
}, 4000);
```

HTML:

```
<my-directive cells=gridCells></my-directive>
```

Directive:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('myDirective', [ function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      cells: '='
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

      scope.gridCells = [];

      scope.$watch(attrs.cells, function(newValue, oldValue) {

        console.log('new: ' + newValue);
        console.log('old: ' + oldValue);

        for(var i = 0; i < scope.cells.length; i++) {
          // populate my scope.gridCells variable with some of the content in the UPDATED cells variable
          if (scope.cells[i].value === '1') {
            gridCells.push(scope.cells[i]);
          }

        }

      });

    },
    template: '{{gridCells.length}}'
  };
}]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`$watchCollection`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watchCollection) instead of `$watch` or do a deepWatch (`scope.$watch(prop, func, true)`) in order to be able to track the changes in the array that has been 2-way bound. It is also better to watch scope property `cells` instead of attribute `cells`

```
scope.$watchCollection('cells', function() {
 //probably you want to reset gridCells here?
  //scope.gridCells = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < scope.cells.length; i++) {
     if (scope.cells[i].value === '1') {
      scope.gridCells.push(scope.cells[i]);
   }
  }
});
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/CEma7F?p=preview)**